# For Loop increasing textBox ID. C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, for-loop

I have 100 `textBoxes`, I want to set a value to all of them using a for loop.

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    textBox1.AppendText("a");
}
```

but the `textBox` ID has to change dynamically like `textBox1`,`textBox2`,`textBox3` etc...

How can I do this?

Comment: What platform are you using? ASP.NET, Windows Forms, Xamarin Forms ???

Comment: I'm using Windows forms.

Comment: store them in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfTextBoxes; i++)
{
    var tb = this.Controls.Find("textBox" + i, true).FirstOrDefault();
    if(tb != null)
      tb.Text = "hello " + i;
}
```

[More on `Find` method.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_Control_ControlCollection_Find_System_String_System_Boolean_)

Answer (score 0):

Put all the TextBoxes in a list.

Or put them in a control and then query them. Call this method with typeof TextBox.

```
public IEnumerable<Control> GetAll(Control control,Type type)
{
    var controls = control.Controls.Cast<Control>();

    return controls.SelectMany(ctrl => GetAll(ctrl,type))
                              .Concat(controls)
                              .Where(c => c.GetType() == type);
}
```

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, you can also pas the Form to this method.
Or query the controls directy from the form.

Comment: Maybe.  But it's probably Winforms.

Comment: You don't need to put them in a control.  You just need to enumerate the Controls collection and pick the right ones to work on.

Comment: Or pass the form to your method.

Comment: ew. why not `.OfType`?

Comment: gettype is clearer.  If you don't like his code, post better code.

Comment: `OfType` is not the same here - the GetAll call is recursive.